# How to hide something from custom home page with php code?

Tags: php, customization, homepage

I need help to get the issue resolved. I have a wordpress custom-made site and it is with a custom home page. The index page of the wordpress site is used for updates purpose(blog). I want to hide something and not displaying on the custom home page. When the time i use "is_home()", the thing on blogging page is hiding and the thing is hiding when the time i use "is_page()". What code should i use to make it hide only on custom home page? Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to hide? Please paste the code for the function in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
!is_front_page()
```

Or

```
is_front_page()
```

But it depends on what the function is.

Comment: This is the code i am trying to use. But it doesn't work for me. I'm trying to get it work.
`<?php if (is_home() || is_single() || is_page() || is_archive() || is_404() || is_tag()) { ?>
<style>
#kitchen-cabinet-homeSlide {background:url(/slider/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat; width:950px; height:540px;}
</style>
<?php } elseif (is_front_page()) { ?><?php } ?>`

Comment: Can you click the arrow and give me a vote if you found it useful thanks.